# Please suggest me an easy software to regulate watermark transparency

Tags: images, software-recommendation, copyright

Please suggest to me a good watermark easy soft. I would like to regulate watermark transparency on my images.

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit unclear, Do you ant a software to make a image transparent or do you want a software too add a watermark? What does this have to do with copyright? Also you might add a bit info about your use case and skill level. Easy for me might not mean easy for you. Easy for you might mean hard for me if for example the software has no scripting interface (scripting is often the easiest way for a lot of tasks, because what can be easier than doing it in the background forever). Anyway use imagemagik, cheap, easy and widely deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any serious multilayer photo editing program you can make a watermark image or text in a new layer and then adjust that layer partially transparent (=reduce the layer opacity). A flattened version of the image = your watermarked version. Try Krita if you need freeware.

There exists free software which can add a watermark to every image in a folder. If you need it, check for ex. IrfanView.

How to make existing watermarks fully transparent or otherwise restore the underlying image? This question surely is also interesting for many people. In this site it probably will be closed soon because it's easily considered as asking help for criminal actions. But one workaround software for that trick exists. It's a banking application. Pay with it the price of the image and you'll get a watermark free version.

Comment: Now I can make a wartermark in a new layer but how can I save this layer to add the warrtermark to other images without preparing it again?

Comment: @Vitaly you probably can keep 2 images opened at the same time. Copy and paste it from one image to another. You may need to move and scale it.

Comment: So I need to save some base image with a layer containing wartermark and then to copy this to another image as I anderstood but I didn't see how to scale it.

Comment: @Vitaly prepare one image which has nothing but different versions of your watermark. You need different sizes (= pixel dimensions), transparencies, angle positions and colors. From there you can copy and paste the right version. Scaling is possible with transformation tools. Find them from yopu program's toolset. In Krita it's aside of the move tool. Radical scaling make bitmap images blury, so have different sizes prepared.

Comment: What is 'mask' in menu of any image editing program. Maybe it is better using mask for my purpose?

Comment: @Vitaly what program you use? Generally masks are curves or bitmap shapes which are used to make parts of the image partially or fully transparent. In Photoshop they also are used to limit the area and strength of effects.

Comment: I use old Paint Shop Pro and see menu 'masks'  there, but I have never  got any idea about what is benefit of it and where to use this 'mask'.

Comment: @Vitaly Scaling in PSP5: make a selection and use the deformation tool. It's just below the looking glass in the std vertical toolbox. It rotates, stretches and squeezes the selected image part.

Comment: Ok. How to maintain aspect ratio in this case? I mean while using grips of deformation tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87597/discussion-between-user287001-and-vitaly).